# Deriving Number of Partitions in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

We deal with large datasets in our project and hence we encounter performance issues in our Spark SQL queries (especially in Joins) quite often. Hence, I am trying to figure out ways to optimize these queries.

Can anyone please help me understand -

How to determine the no. of partitions a particular table is currently split into. (this will help in determining whether to repartition the table for optimizing Joins)

How to determine the optimal no. of partitions that need to be set for a `Join` to function optimally based on the participating tables' sizes ? Is there any rule of thumb for deriving this number for the Join/Aggregation etc to perform optimally ?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `df.getNumPartitions()`?

Comment: I need to find out the value thru the SQL API queries. Can you help please ?